# Which Control to Bind ObservableCollection<string> to To Display Text Only

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ObservableCollection

What should I bind it to if I just want a list of Labels/Text?

When I use a ListBox/View or GridView I get a bunch of functionality I don't want like selecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `ItemsControl`. It will display a list of bound data with no other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this:

```
string output = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myObservableCollection);
```

then you bind output to the label or text you like...

see here: [String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)